# What are the basic system requirement for installing asp.net mvc 2 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

What are the basic system requirement for installing asp.net mvc 2 application.

**Edited:-**
If I want to host the asp.net mvc 2 application on the windows XP then is there any special requirement like IIS version, Framework, service packs or else ?

Comment: Do you mean hardware requirements or software prerequisites?

Comment: both software (OS/IIS/Framework) as well as Hardware also .

Comment: [The download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9) has the software requirements—I'm going to vote to move this to SuperUser though, I think you'll get better answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS per the [MVC download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9), any of the following operating systems:

> Windows Server 2003,
>   Windows Server 2008,
>   Windows Vista,
>   Windows XP

Required framework:

> .NET 3.5 SP1 Framework

As per the [framework download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325fd-ae52-4e35-b531-508d977d32a6&displaylang=en), it has the requirements:

- Processor:

  - 400 MHz Pentium processor or equivalent (Minimum)
  - 1GHz Pentium processor or equivalent (Recommended)
- RAM:96 MB (Minimum); 256 MB (Recommended)
- Hard Disk: Up to 500 MB of available space may be required